# Return generic class type

Tags: java, class, generics

I have a method that might return Class A or Class B. How can I define its return type to be generic, independent of what class type is returned. For e.g.

```
public <Generic_Class_Return_Type> showForm() {
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else 
      return new ClassB();
}
```

Comment: Add the same interface to the classes, return the interface

Comment: One way is to just return Object. But I wanted to know if there is something more generic and appropriate to use

    public Object showForm() {
       if (true)
          return new ClassA();
       else 
          return new ClassB();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if you need generics in this case, however you can parameterize either the whole class or just the method and then use reflection like this:

```
public <T> T getForm() {
  Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((true) ? Foo.class : Bar.class);
  Constructor<T> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
  return ctor.newInstance();
}
```

However if you specify your use case, we can further suggest if going generics is the way, or if you'd better use standard polymorphism.

Comment: a little typo: `klass` vs `clazz` (I wish the world would adopt `theClass` or `someClass` as a convention)

Comment: Thanks, there are lots of typos actually. First time posting from a phone (and really I regret!) BTW, there should be at least an unchecked cast somewhere, not sure if it compiles at all

Comment: Been there done that... posting from a phone is WAY hard!  Who's gonna create the app that makes it easier??!?

Comment: Not sure if an app can be enough. A useful answer often requires links to external resources, and the code should be run before posting, but this tasks are difficult or indeed impossible on a mobile device. I just couldn't resist the temptation to answer this one :P But admittedly it's a trivial one, and in spite of this the over all quality is quite low. Hope it helps , still, since nobody else posted examples with generics

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interface both classes implement like this:

```
public SomeInterface showForm() {
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else 
      return new ClassB();
}

class ClassA implements SomeInterface{}
class ClassB implements SomeInterface{}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I thought there is something in Java Generics to handle this?

Comment: No there are no generic return types. You can make the class containing the method generic and make that function return the generic type but nevertheless you would have either a SuperClass OR an Interface bot ClassA and ClassB derive from/implement

Comment: If it wasn't possible to use a type variable as the return type, List<T>.get(int) could not return a T and you'd have to cast all the times

Answer (score 0):

```
public object showForm()
{
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else
      return new ClassB(); 
}
```

or

```
public superClassName showForm()
{
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else
      return new ClassB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to return them as an Object.

```
public Object showForm() {
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else 
      return new ClassB();
}
```

It's not so useful though, a far more useful solution would be to have them either extend a common class or implement a common interface.

```
public CommonInterface showForm() {
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else 
      return new ClassB();
}

class ClassA implements CommonInterface { }
class ClassB implements CommonInterface { }
interface CommonInterface { }
```

Or

```
public CommonClass showForm() {
   if (true)
      return new ClassA();
   else 
      return new ClassB();
}

class ClassA extends CommonClass { }
class ClassB extends CommonClass { }
class CommonClass { }
```

**Generics**

If you want to use generics then `ClassA` and `ClassB` would need to be the same Class, modified by some generic type eg. `Class<T>`. Whether generics are relevant all depends on the implementation of your classes. You're probably best to go with an interface or base class.